# Filtering Nested Array Object to Use in FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a `FlatList` that renders following data successfully.

```
const messages = [
  {
    "user": {
      "id": 4,
      "userId": "1561652136"
    },
    "resultsCount": 9,
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 252,
        "senderId": 147,
        "recipientId": 4,
        "body": "some text"
      },
      {
        "id": 253,
        "senderId": 147,
        "recipientId": 4,
        "body": "some other text"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "id": 14,
      "userId": "6155616153"
    },
    "resultsCount": 17,
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 275,
        "senderId": 147,
        "recipientId": 145,
        "body": "can you find also this text"
      },
      {
        "id": 276,
        "senderId": 145,
        "recipientId": 147,
        "body": "you should find this text"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to filter `messages` according to user input. So, I am trying to achieve search functionality.

```
if (userInput) {
  const newData = messages.filter(message => {
    const messageData = message ? message.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase()
    const textData = text.toUpperCase()
    return messageData.indexOf(textData) > -1
  })
  setFilteredData(newData)
} else {
  setFilteredData(messages)
}
```

Above code is not working since user should only be able to search in the `body`.

For example if the `userInput` is `can`, `newData` should be like that:

```
[
  {
    "user": {
      "id": 14,
      "userId": "6155616153"
    },
    "resultsCount": 17,
    "results": [
      {
        "id": 275,
        "senderId": 147,
        "recipientId": 145,
        "body": "can you find also this text"
      },
      {
        "id": 276,
        "senderId": 145,
        "recipientId": 147,
        "body": "you should find this text"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You need to search in the body of each result of each item, not in the item itself. Also, message would be a better name than item, given that you're filtering over messages.

Comment: That is my problem. I cannot search in multiple `body`. Do you mind show me how I can do that?

Comment: You are right about the naming. I changed it as `message`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to aggregate the bodies of each message's results and test them for the presence of a given text. This assumes the availability of the `messages` array, per your original posted code.

```
function findMessages(text) {
  return messages.filter(function(message) {
    const bodies = message.results.map(result => result.body).join('\n');
    return bodies.includes(text);
  });
}

console.log(findMessages("can"));
```

Comment: Instead of joining the bodies together you could also use `message.results.some(result => result.body.includes(text))`

Comment: @3limin4t0r that's a great option, thanks for proposing it. I won't steal your glory by modifying my response but I'll use that technique next time.